# Special representation of real numbers as infinite products

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, probability-theory, binomial-distribution, decimal-expansion

*Final update on 11/29/2019: I have worked on this a bit more, and wrote an article summarizing all the main findings. You can read it [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/chaos-attractors-in-machine-learning-systems).*

I am looking for a reference regarding the following. Every real number $x\in [1, 2]$ is uniquely representable as a product of distinct factors of the form $1+2^{-k}$, that is

$$x=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \Big(1+\frac{b_k}{2^k} \Big) \mbox{ with } b_k\in \{0, 1\}.$$ 
The algorithm to find the $b_k$'s is a simple version of the greedy algorithm. I could not find any reference to this fact, except a small note in the Wikipedia entry for logarithms. It is said to be related to Feynman's algorithm, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Feynman's_algorithm). If all $b_k$'s are equal to one, then $x=2.384231029... = \frac{1}{1-z}$ where $z$ is the Pell constant (see [here](https://experimentalmath.wordpress.com/mathematical-constants/), [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellConstant.html) and [here](http://oeis.org/A141848).)

The reason for my interest is because I am studying numeration systems (see my numerous questions on Math.StackExchange and Stats.StackExchange, most recently [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432136/random-variables-x-z-such-that-z-and-sqrtx-z-have-the-same-distribut)), and in particular, numeration systems where the digits are random numbers. In this case, it means I am interested in the case where the $b_k$'s are independent Bernouilli random variables of parameter $p_k$ (for instance $p_k=\frac{1}{2}$ or $p_k = 2^{-k}$.)

**Update**

It turns out that this system is ill-conditioned. A number can actually have two different representations, for instance
$$ \frac{3}{2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^1} = \Big(1+\frac{1}{2^2}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{1}{2^3}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{1}{2^4}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{1}{2^8}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{1}{2^{16}}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{1}{2^{32}}\Big)\cdots$$
More precisely,
$$\frac{3}{2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^1} =\Big(1+\frac{1}{2^3}\Big).\prod_{k=1}^\infty\Big(1+\frac{1}{2^{2^k}} \Big).$$

If you use the greedy algorithm to find the $b_k$'s, it will lead to the first (leftmost) representation: $\frac{3}{2}= 1+\frac{1}{2^1}$. Yet if $b_k$ has a Bernouilli distribution of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ (that is 50% of zeros, 50% of ones), then $x$ also has some statistical distribution, pictured below (the chart below shows the percentile distribution):

[image]

The distribution (CDF) in question is very well approximated by $F(x) = \log_{\lambda} x$, with $x \in [1,  \lambda]$. Here $\lambda =2.384231029...$ is the constant discussed earlier. See below the chart picturing $F(x)$ in blue, and its logarithmic approximation in red. The CDF is the inverse of the percentile distribution.

[image]

Now this is becoming very interesting: compare this chart with the one obtained for continued radicals in section 2.2 [in this article](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/math-fun-infinite-nested-radicals-of-random-variables). How similar! I plan on sharing my spreadsheet with the computations required to produce the percentile and PDF distribution.

The chart below shows the approximation error $\log_\lambda x - F(x)$ between the logarithmic approximation and the exact CDF, with $x\in [1, \lambda]$.
[image]

If $b_k$ has a Bernoulli distribution of parameter $p=\frac{1}{6}$ (rather than $p=\frac{1}{2}$), then $x$ has a more chaotic distribution, see percentile distribution below:

[image]

To the contrary, if $b_k$ is uniform on $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ then the distribution is much smoother, see percentile distribution below:

[image]

Comment: Is this simply a reference request?  It seems like you already know how to prove the theorem.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Saulspatz: I think I know how to prove it, but I haven't tried. It's mostly a reference question, and maybe if someone has any idea how to tackle the brand new problem where the digits are random numbers. It's a very exciting topic leading to all sorts of weird distributions that have fractal-like behavior, see https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/math-fun-infinite-nested-radicals-of-random-variables

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038089/feynmans-representation-theory-for-numbers-between-1-and-2/

Comment: Actually, I even wrote myself on this topic, a while back: https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/difficult-probably-problem-distribution-of-digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not an answer but too long for a comment.**

$$\log x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac{b_k}{2^k}\right)\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{2^k}$$ is able to represent all numbers in $[0,\log x_1]$ (where $x_1$ is your constant). The gap between $\log\left(1+\dfrac{b_k}{2^k}\right)$ and $\dfrac{b_k}{2^k}$ quickly decreases as $k$ gets larger, and the two numeration systems become virtually identical.

The successive "weights" of the bits are

$$0.40546510\cdots\\0.22314355\cdots\\0.11778303\cdots\\0.06062462\cdots\\0.03077165\cdots\\0.01550418\cdots\\\cdots$$

to be compared to

$$0.5\\0.25\\0.125\\0.0625\\0.03125\\0.015625\\\cdots$$

The non-uniqueness is explained by the convexity of the function, implying

$$\log\left(1+\frac1{2^k}\right)<2\log\left(1+\frac1{2^{k+1}}\right)$$ so that a term can be reconstructed by higher order terms.

To obtain approximations of the $\text{cdf}$ of the random variable, using $n$ bits, you associate to the bits of all integers $k$ in $[0,2^n-1]$ the sum of the corresponding weights; these sums form the abscissas and the ordinates are $\dfrac k{2^n}$, but there are inversions.

The higher $n$, the more the portion of the curve between two points tends to a line segment.